# split dataframe using common rows dynamically

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe is called data:

```
**Select.Actions**     **Current.State**  **Next.State**
Hire new staff         Out of Benchmark  Withinbenchmark
Hire new staff         Out of Benchmark  Withinbenchmark
Discuss with Customer  Withinbenchmark   Withinbenchmark
Discuss with Customer  Withinbenchmark   Withinbenchmark
Discuss with Customer  Out of Benchmark  Out of Benchmark
Fire new staff         Out of Benchmark  Withinbenchmark
Discuss with Customer  Withinbenchmark   Withinbenchmark
Discuss with Customer  Out of Benchmark  Withinbenchmark
Fire new staff         Out of Benchmark  Withinbenchmar
```

I want to have separate data frame based on the values of Select.Actions.

```
#select First Column of dataframe
d<-data[1]
```

Then I want to match data with the input of d. Because d is dynamic and it will change over time so I wrote a loop to split data frame to different dataframe:

```
    split<-for(i in 1:length(d)){
z[i]<-subset(data, data[,"Select.Actions"] %in% d[i],select=c(Current.State,Next.State))}
```

Then I got the following warning message.

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = list(Current.State = integer(0),  :
  provided 2 variables to replace 1 variables
```

Could you please advise me in terms of logic?

and the output is NULL.

Comment: what stops you from using the `?split` function?

Comment: If I use split function also I have to use a loop, because as I mentioned the  input of Select.Actions is dynamic and it will change by the user. So I need to write a dynamic code to split the dataframe.

Comment: `d<-data[1]` doesn't select any columns, btw. You need `data[,1]`. I dont quite get what youre doing. What values can `d` take?

Comment: When I use data[1], I saved the first column as a list. typeof(d) is list. Then I want to match the items in d with the data frame to filter it. Then I want to have different data frame based on the values inside d.

Comment: You are substituting multiple rows of data in a single row. `z[i]<-subset(data, ...`  returns more than one row and two columns. You need to cater for that.

Comment: how can I fix that? could you please help?

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: When I run the programme it shows NULL

Comment: I mean expected output? See my solution in answer and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning multiple rows and columns in `z[i]<-subset(data, ...`, you can use `rbind`. I'd suggest not using `subset` as explained by Hadely [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html). Let me know if `dplyr` solution below works for you.

```
library(dplyr)
data <- read.table(text = 'Select.Actions,Current.State,Next.State
Hire new staff,Out of Benchmark,Withinbenchmark
Hire new staff,Out of Benchmark,Withinbenchmark
Discuss with Customer,Withinbenchmark,Withinbenchmark
Discuss with Customer,Withinbenchmark,Withinbenchmark
Discuss with Customer,Out of Benchmark,Out of Benchmark
Fire new staff,Out of Benchmark,Withinbenchmark
Discuss with Customer,Withinbenchmark,Withinbenchmark
Discuss with Customer,Out of Benchmark,Withinbenchmark
Fire new staff, Out of Benchmark,Withinbenchmar', 
                   header = TRUE, sep =",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



z <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(data))
{
  interm_data <- data %>% filter(Select.Actions == data[i,1]) %>% select(Current.State, Next.State) 
  if(is.null(z))
  {
    z<- interm_data
  }else{
    z<- rbind(z,interm_data)
  }
  print(data[i,1])
  print(interm_data)

}
```

**Updated **

Based on user's comments.

```
z <- list()
trim <- function (x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x)
for(i in unique(data$Select.Actions))
{
  z[[trim(i)]] <- data %>% filter(Select.Actions == i) %>% select(Current.State, Next.State) 
}
list2env(z ,.GlobalEnv)
# Now you will have 3 data sets `Hire new staff`, `Fire new staff` and `Discuss with customer` in your workspace.
```

However, I'd not use the loop in the first place for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a duplication in the output. In this case, I want to have only 3 data frames. [1] Hire new staff  ,[2] Discuss with Customer and [3] Fire new staff. I want to filter the dataframe based on different actions and save each dataframe as a new one.

Comment: Instead of nrow(data), I used d<-unique(data[1]). to solve the duplication problem, still I cannot save each dataframe separately.

Comment: How about the new updated code, removes duplications and creates 3 data frame separately?

Comment: Perfect, it works. Just one more question, how can I call 3 dataframe dynamically from global enviroment. because the name of each variable will be change when user selects different actions.